# How to check an existence of the nested key in an object in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nested, key, aggregation

So the problem is that I must find the number of hotels in each state by using ***"aggregate"*** function and "group" operator in MongoDB. Hotels have to have at least 4.5 stars and have an attribute ***"Wi-Fi"*** with value true. I attached below the link to the image with structure of objects (screen from Robo3T)

[image: Object structure]

***"attributes"*** is a key of the business collection and it can have nested keys like "Wi-Fi" but it is not necessary. I don't know how to check an existence of this key along with true value. I wrote some code but without checking it (see below).

```
db.business.aggregate([
{$match: {"categories": {$in: ["Hotels"]}, "stars":{$gte: 3.5}}},
{$group: {_id:"$state", count:{$sum:1}}}])
```

I need help with this example and a lot explanation.

Comment: Try adding  `"attributes.Wi-Fi":true` to the `$match` stage.  Checking existence is not necessary if you only want true values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to check the existence of some field as long as you need to check that this field is true
so, just add `'attributes.Wi-Fi': true` to the match object

so the query should be

```
'attributes.Wi-Fi': true
```

if you need to check that some attribute like Wi-Fi does not exist or equal to false
then the query should be like

1-

```
'attributes.Wi-Fi': { $ne: true } // wi-fi attribute is not equal to true, this means either wi-fi does not exist or exists but equals any value but not true
```

2- or using the $or operator

```
$or: [
    {
        'attributes.Wi-Fi': { $exists: false } // wifi attribute does not exist
    },
    {
        'attributes.Wi-Fi': false // or exists and equal to false
    }
]
```

just add any of these queries if needed to the $match object

Comment: Yeah, it really works. I thought that checking an existence is necessary in this example but not, only checking true finally works here. Thank you for the explanation and examples!